# iOS (Swift) で、動画撮影中のデバイス回転時の処理について

Tags: ios, swift

はじめまして。

現在、 Swift で動画撮影アプリを制作しておりますが、デバイスを縦横に回転させた際の処理で困っています。

デバイスを傾けたときに、撮影枠は縦横対応にうまく対応できたのですが、それに伴って被写体がうまく回転してくれません。いろいろ調べていますが、アプリ開発の初心者ということもあり、いまいち修正ポイントがわかっていません。

画面回転時のメソッドの中で、 `CameraEngine.swift` の `startup` 処理の何かを再度、設定するべきなのかなど、初心者なりに悩んでおります。

どなたか、アドバイスをいただけないでしょうか？何卒よろしくお願いいたします。

以下に、修正すべきところと思われるソースの一部を抜粋させていただきます。

【ViewController.swift】

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // カメラエンジンスタート
    self.cameraEngine.startup()

    videoLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.layerWithSession(self.cameraEngine.captureSession) as AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer

    // 画面セットアップ
    setupScreen()
}

// 画面回転時に呼び出される
override func willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation(toInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation, duration: NSTimeInterval) {

    // 画面セットアップ
    setupScreen()
}

// 画面セットアップ
func setupScreen(){
    // ビデオレイヤー設定
    videoLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
    videoLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(videoLayer)
}
```

【CameraEngine.swift】

```
func startup(){

    // video input
    self.videoDevice.activeVideoMinFrameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30)

    var captureDevice: AVCaptureDevice?
    // バックカメラ
    captureDevice = self.videoDevice

    let videoInput = AVCaptureDeviceInput.deviceInputWithDevice(captureDevice, error: nil) as AVCaptureDeviceInput

    self.captureSession.addInput(videoInput)

    // audio input
    let audioInput = AVCaptureDeviceInput.deviceInputWithDevice(self.audioDevice, error: nil)  as AVCaptureDeviceInput
    self.captureSession.addInput(audioInput);

    // video output
    var videoDataOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
    videoDataOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: self.recordingQueue)
    videoDataOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true
    videoDataOutput.videoSettings = [
        kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey : kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange
    ]
    self.captureSession.addOutput(videoDataOutput)

    self.height = videoDataOutput.videoSettings["Height"] as Int!
    self.width = videoDataOutput.videoSettings["Width"] as Int!

    // audio output
    var audioDataOutput = AVCaptureAudioDataOutput()
    audioDataOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: self.recordingQueue)
    self.captureSession.addOutput(audioDataOutput)

    self.captureSession.startRunning()
}
```

【追記】20150121
[image: デバイス横のイメージ]
デバイス横のイメージ

[image: デバイス縦のイメージ]
デバイス縦のイメージ

Comment: "デバイスを傾けたときに、撮影枠は縦横対応にうまく対応できたのですが、それに伴って被写体がうまく回転してくれません。"という文章が何を表しているのか、現状どうで、理想はこうなってほしいというのを整理して書いていただけないでしょうか。

Comment: 現状は、デバイスを横向きにした場合、被写体がデバイスと逆の横向きに写ってしまいます。顔を写していた場合、顔も回転し横向きになるイメージです。撮影ボタンは、ちゃんと下に配置しなおされてます。デバイスをよこにしても顔が横向きに倒れないようにしたいです。

Comment: 「写っています」というのはUI上で、でしょうか。それともファイルに記録された後、でしょうか。もしUI上で、とのことであれば、デバイスを横にする前のスクリーンショットと、横にした後のスクリーンショットなどを質問に貼っていただけると答えが得やすいのかなと思います。

Comment: ご対応ありがとうございます
写っているのはUI上になります。
スクリーンショットを追加させていただきました。